# Gapless video playback software for mac

Tags: mac, video

Is there any gapless video playback for mac?

The idea is creating a playlist of videos and play that playlist in an endless loop but avoiding stopping/skipping/gapping between them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) - if the GUI with it's numerous settings don't do it for you, you can also run it from the terminal window and set exactly how much of each video in the playlist to play before proceeding to the next video in the list and then looping back to the first.